# Auto suggestions for Python snippets trigger only on Ctrl+Space

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Previously I had another autosuggestion behaviour for snippets:
I type in a Python snippet alias and in a few milliseconds I see a list of suggestions, including code snippets on top. Now, I see the following:

[Screenshot w/o snippets in suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8FOY.png)

After pressing Ctrl+Space:

[Screenshot after pressing Ctrl+Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6N0K.png)

After this autosuggestion on-the-fly starts working for this snippet - "inp". For each snippet that hasn't been used with Ctrl+Space, I will need to press the shortcut.

The issue holds for both Jupyter notebooks and Python scripts.
I want to restore suggestions of code snippets on-the-fly, without pressing the Ctrl+Space combination.

[Some suggestion-related settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8sL0.png)

I tried to modify some settings with no success.

Reading https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets also didn't provide much insight into the issue.

Comment: What VS Code version are you on? If 1.75.0, then this is possibly this: [Visual Studio Code's recent update is disrupting autocompletion](/q/75340072)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the 1.75.0 version of VScode. Running

```
sudo apt -y update
```

and installing 1.75.1 is enough to resolve the issue.